# How to hide the Div at the Click of the Button in MVC

Tags: jquery

My application is in MVC3.I want a particular Div in my View to Hide at the click of the button.
Below is my Code that i tried.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
 $("#btnCompare").click(function () {
 if(MyCondition)
 {
    for(MyLoop)
    {
    }
}
}
});
```

My this code is not working.As well as i want to Div to Hide after the Click is called.
Please suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
     $("#btnCompare").click(function () {
     $(".YourDiv").hide("slow");
     if(MyCondition)
     {
        for(MyLoop)
        {
        }
     }
    });
});
```

YourDiv is the Class of the Div you want to hide.If there is no ID in the Div Tag then Assign a Class like this

```
<div class="YourDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

You can hide a element using jQUery's `.hide()` method.

> **`jQuery.hide()`** Hide the matched elements.

You can also hide the div with an animation.

Check out my sample and this **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/HbT4w/).**

#### Sample 1

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#btnCompare1").click(function () {
       $("#myDiv").hide()
    });
});
```

#### Sample 2 (animated)

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#btnCompare2").click(function () {
       $("#myDiv").hide("slow");
    });
});
```

#### More Information

- **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/HbT4w/).**
- [jQuery.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#btnCompare").click(function () {
        if(MyCondition)
        {
            $("div.SomeTargetCssClass").hide();
        }
     }
});
```

It should be as simple as that; you can target the DIV by ID (`$("#divid")`) or use the code above.  Make sure MyCondition is also being evaluated, because that can be the culprit sometimes.

Also, you may want to view source to make sure the button's ID evaluates to btnCompare; on the client it may have rendered a little differently...